# Pivot Table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I have a table with many columns which specifies if an error is valid or not. I need output in such a way that columns names which specify the error as rows and count of valid and invalid fields for each error.

Example of similar input and expected output below

```
id   name            txn_column_name  flag1 flag2 flag3 
1    Resident Count  resident_ct      Y     Y     N
2    Incident Count  incident_ct      Y     Y     Y
3    Facility Status facil_stat       N     N     N
```

Output required

```
Col1_name Y_Count    N_Count
flag1       2            1
flag2       2            1
flag3       1            2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using Oracle's `UNPIVOT` operator here:

```
SELECT
    flag AS Col1_name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS Y_Count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS N_Count
FROM yourTable
UNPIVOT
(
    val FOR (flag) IN (
        flag1 AS 'flag1',
        flag2 AS 'flag2',
        flag3 AS 'flag3'
    )
)
GROUP BY
    flag
ORDER BY
    flag;
```

### Demo

Another straightforward option uses a series of unions:

```
SELECT
    'flag1' AS Col1_name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN flag1 = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS Y_Count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN flag1 = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS N_Count
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'flag2', COUNT(CASE WHEN flag2 = 'Y' THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN flag2 = 'N' THEN 1 END)
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'flag3', COUNT(CASE WHEN flag3 = 'Y' THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN flag3 = 'N' THEN 1 END)
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank You very much... It was very helpful :)